# Using mapply to perform operations on lists of vectors: trouble with index specification

Tags: r, list, vector, mapply

I have two lists (A and B), each comprising 5 vectors of length 3. I also have a 3x3 matrix Z.

I want to perform operations on the elements of A, using B and Z, and output it to a 3x5 matrix. I am able to do this successfully using a for loop as follows

```
#Create two lists of vectors
A = list(c(1,2,1), c(2,1,2), c(3,2,2),c(1,2,5),c(1,4,2))
B = list(c(2,3,1), c(1,3,4), c(2,5,2), c(2,4,1),c(1,4,1))
#Create 3x3 matrix
Z = rbind(c(2,3,5),c(3,2,3), c(1,1,1))

#initialize empty 3x5 matrix
Y = matrix(NA,3,5)

for (i in 1:3)
{
  for (j in 1:5)
  {
    #Take the ith element of the jth vector from A, and divide it by
    #the dot product of the jth vector from B and the ith row of Z
    Y[i,j] = A[[j]][i] / sum(B[[j]]*Z[i,])
  }
}
```

This returns (for Y)

```
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
[1,] 0.05555556 0.06451613 0.10344828 0.04761905 0.05263158
[2,] 0.13333333 0.04761905 0.09090909 0.11764706 0.28571429
[3,] 0.16666667 0.25000000 0.22222222 0.71428571 0.33333333
```

I'm trying to figure out how to use mapply to make this more efficient.

So far I've got this:

```
mapply(function(x,y,z) x/sum(y*z), x=A,y=B,z = Z)
```

but this isn't working correctly.  I reckon that perhaps splitting up the task into maybe two separate mapply's may do the trick, and perhaps I'd need to reorganize the matrices and lists so that the indices match up somehow. I've had some success with the apply family of functions, but I'm not fluent enough yet to figure out how to best approach this problem. I'd appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to break it into two steps, like you thought. Here's a way to do it:

```
BZ <- lapply(B, FUN = function(y) 
    apply(Z, 1, FUN = function(x) sum(y*x)))

mapply(function(x,y) x / y, x = A, y = BZ)

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
[1,] 0.05555556 0.06451613 0.10344828 0.04761905 0.05263158
[2,] 0.13333333 0.04761905 0.09090909 0.11764706 0.28571429
[3,] 0.16666667 0.25000000 0.22222222 0.71428571 0.33333333
```

Comment: Ah! thank you so much. Your answer not only solves my problem, but also will help me become better with the apply family. Much appreciated!